# How could i make HashSet as parameter to the HashMap?

Tags: java, collections

I have to maintain the list of indexes for each of the key value in HashMap.
So i declared HashMap as

`HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer> hset =  new HashSet<Integer>()> hm = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer> hset =  new HashSet<Integer>()>();`
but the above declaration seems to be not correct.
So i declared it as

```
HashSet<Integer> hset =  new HashSet<Integer>();
```

but here the problem is,how could i declare the type of objects stored in HashSet i,e Integer, bacause in the above declaration the HashSet is rawtype.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to do `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hset = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();` so later you could do `hset.put(1, new HashSet<Integer>());` . I hope, this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is simple generic types. I din't understand what confused you here. Try giving some hands on generics. And later adding different type of objects to declared variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to add more here,
You need to initialize your outer Map like below

```
HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> map =  new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>();
```

and inner collection like this

```
HashSet<Integer> hset =  new HashSet<Integer>();
```

And you insert the values like below in map and your hash set.

```
hset.add(1);
hset.add(2);
map.put(100,hset); 

hset =  new HashSet<Integer>();
hset.add(3);
hset.add(4);
map.put(101,hset);
```

So every time you need new instance of HashSet to put in map.

You can get inner HashSet by using Map key you used to insert.

```
 HashSet<Integer> hset=map.get(100); //Same map
```

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG it seems you are in so hurry to get the answer but you are not analyzing your problem yourself. Just checkout why your declaration din't work.

Comment: @Viraj   if i have 1000 keys in hashmap, i need to maintain 1000 hashSet right?

Comment: Yes..I think you need to mention, what you want achieve using collection. then we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your declaration should look like

`HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> map =  new HashMap<Integer>,HashSet<Integer>>`

Second declaration you have provided for Hashset is correct. Its not raw type. **Did you try adding a any other type of element to it ?**

Comment: This works, though generally speaking it should be `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();`

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes, actually interface type should be used rather than implementation type while declaring

Comment: yeah!!! that worked... but during the insertion of the elements into the map its giving  error as                                                                     "The method put(Integer, HashSet<Integer>) in the type HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"     . the code is                                                           for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
        {
         a[k]= b[p[k]];
         map.put(a[k], k);
        }

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG yes, it wont work. You are just adding a entry for long, int pair while your value type is a set of integers, not integer. If you want this to happen then declare your map as Map<Long, Intger> map = new HashMap<Long,Integer>.

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG what type of a is. If its integer then **`new HashMap<Integer,Integer>`**

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work :

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
```

you can easily Set Using `Map` tag only .

**or**

- Create the Object Of `Hashmap` and put the value from Refrence. it will work